# Nested if statements with same else expressions in python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I am wondering whether there is a nice solution in python for nested `if` statements where all `else` have the same expression, without having to rewrite that expression?

In the example below I rewrite expr3 for both else statements:

```
if cond1:
    expr1
    if cond2:
        expr2
    else:
        expr3
else:
    expr3
```

The issue above is that `expr1` is conditional on `cond1`, but not `cond2`. Unless there is something like an "all else" expression, the only simplification I see at the moment, is to break it into two statements:

```
if cond1 and cond2:
    expr2
else:
    expr3
```

and

```
if cond1:
    expr1
```

Would be glad to see any other suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

This might help.

```
setExp3 = True
if cond1:
    expr1
    if cond2:
        expr2
        setExp3 = False

if setExp3:
    expr3
```

Comment: Using a boolean `setExp` could be useful to shorten the code!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do it differently:

```
if cond1 :
    expr1
    if cond2 :
        expr2

if not (cond1 and cond2) :
    expr3
```